# add_custom_target multiple dependencies provided by a list

Tags: cmake

```
set(OUTPUT_PATH "some_path/some_path2/")
set(NAME_XML "external/some_folder/somexml.xml")
set(OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "header1.h" "header2.h" "header3.h")

add_custom_target(
        some_target ALL
        DEPENDS ${OUTPUT_PATH}header1.h
        DEPENDS ${OUTPUT_PATH}header2.h
        ......
)

foreach(item ${OUTPUT_DIRECTORY})
message(STATUS "testing..." ${item})
add_custom_command(
        COMMAND python3 ${OUTPUT_PATH}/main.py -n "1" -p "${OUTPUT_PATH}" -f "${NAME_XML}" -o "${item}"
        DEPENDS ${NAME_XML}
        OUTPUT ${OUTPUT_PATH}${item}
        COMMENT "some comment: ${item}"
)
endforeach(item)
```

The goal of this work is for python script to be called if the header file is not found (for each case) or has been modified. Similarly, if the XML file has been modified, I want to regenerate all header files by calling the python script.

The python script allows us to pass individual header files to be generated which is why I have this "foreach". As a result, I want to call it only per the requirements in the above paragraph.

How I can modify the code to achieve that and how I can include the OUTPUT_DIRECTORY as a list in the add_custom_target rather than adding DEPENDS in each line individually as per my code example?

Comment: *DEPENDS* option actually accepts a **list**, not just a single element. That is, `DEPENDS ${OUTPUT_FILES}` would be acceptible. As for collecting output files into variable `OUTPUT_FILES`, you may iterate over `OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` list, and use `list(APPEND)` for append (transformed) element into `OUTPUT_FILES` list.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for, I got it working now. Is there any way that I can use a list and define the items directly there like I did using set? It seems I need to use set and then use foreach and add them one by one based on my solution which seems weird.

Comment: You may try [string(REGEX REPLACE)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/string.html#regex-replace), where `<regular_expression>` matches list elements, one by one, and `<replace_expression>` prepends matching with a specific string (`${OUTPUT_PATH}` in your case).